# How to read .dcm in Xcode using python?

Tags: python, xcode, cocoa, matlab, dicom

I'm trying to create an app for viewing and analyzing DICOM slices. I have done this app in MATLAB, but MATLAB does not have enough tools to build a really nice GUI and 3D picture is bad. So, I was trying to use ITK and VTK to build an app in Xcode for a long period of time but without any success. One day I found xcodeproject PythonDicomDocument - this project (written in python) can read and show DICOM image! I have read a tutorial about python and cocoa but I still can't understand how this project works - it has file **PythonDicomDocumentDocument.py:**

```
from Foundation import *
from AppKit import *
from iiDicom import *

import objc


import dicom
import numpy
import Image


class PythonDicomDocumentDocument(NSDocument):
imageView = objc.IBOutlet('imageView')

def init(self):

    self = super(PythonDicomDocumentDocument, self).init()
    self.image = None
    return self

def windowNibName(self):

    return u"PythonDicomDocumentDocument"

def windowControllerDidLoadNib_(self, aController):
    super(PythonDicomDocumentDocument, self).windowControllerDidLoadNib_(aController)
    if self.image:
        self.imageView.setImageScaling_(NSScaleToFit)
        self.imageView.setImage_(self.image)


def dataOfType_error_(self, typeName, outError):
    return None

def readFromData_ofType_error_(self, data, typeName, outError):
    return NO

def readFromURL_ofType_error_(self, absoluteURL, typeName, outError):
    if absoluteURL.isFileURL():
        slice = iiDcmSlice.alloc().initWithDicomFileSlice_(absoluteURL.path())

        dicomImage = slice.sliceAsNSImage_context_(True, None)

        if dicomImage:
            self.image = dicomImage
                            #self.image = dicomImage

            return True, None

    return False, None
```

and **file main.m:**

```
**#import "<"Python/Python.h>**

**#import "<"Cocoa/Cocoa.h>**


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *resourcePath = [mainBundle resourcePath];
    NSArray *pythonPathArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: resourcePath,               [resourcePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"PyObjC"],      @"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/Extras/lib/python/", nil];

setenv("PYTHONPATH", [[pythonPathArray componentsJoinedByString:@":"] UTF8String], 1);

    NSArray *possibleMainExtensions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"py", @"pyc",            @"pyo", nil];
    NSString *mainFilePath = nil;

for (NSString *possibleMainExtension in possibleMainExtensions) {
    mainFilePath = [mainBundle pathForResource: @"main" ofType: possibleMainExtension];
    if ( mainFilePath != nil ) break;
}

if ( !mainFilePath ) {
    [NSException raise: NSInternalInconsistencyException format: @"%s:%d main() Failed to find the Main.{py,pyc,pyo} file in the application wrapper's Resources directory.", __FILE__, __LINE__];
}

Py_SetProgramName("/usr/bin/python");
Py_Initialize();
PySys_SetArgv(argc, (char **)argv);

    const char *mainFilePathPtr = [mainFilePath UTF8String];

    FILE *mainFile = fopen(mainFilePathPtr, "r");



int result = PyRun_SimpleFile(mainFile, (char *)[[mainFilePath lastPathComponent] UTF8String]);



if ( result != 0 )
    [NSException raise: NSInternalInconsistencyException
                format: @"%s:%d main() PyRun_SimpleFile failed with file '%@'.  See console for errors.", __FILE__, __LINE__, mainFilePath];

[pool drain];

return result;
```

}

So I want to "translate" MATLAB code for reading .dcm:

```
directory = uigetdir; % after this command Finder window will appear and user will             choose a folder with .dcm files

fileFolder = directory; % the path to the folder is saved to a variable fileFolder
dirOutput = dir(fullfile(fileFolder,'*.dcm')); % choose files .dcm in specified folder     %and save their names 
fileNames = {dirOutput.name}';

Names = char(fileNames);
numFrames = numel(fileNames); % count the number of files in the folder


    for i = 1:numFrames
    Volume(:,:,i) = dicomread(fullfile(fileFolder,Names(i,:))); % create a 3D array of         %DICOM pixel data
    end;
```

Could anyone please tell me how to run the same code for reading .dcm files in Xcode using python???

I've heard that python and MATLAB are similar.

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations on choosing Python for working with DICOM; the [SciPy](http://www.scipy.org/)/numpy/matplotlib clan is *much* better at dealing with huge amounts of volume data than MATLAB (or at least GNU Octave) in my experience.

Trivia load and display code using [GDCM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gdcm/)'s python bindings, a [ConvertNumpy.py](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/html/ConvertNumpy_8py-example.html) from GDCM's examples and [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import gdcm
import ConvertNumpy
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def loadDicomImage(filename):
    reader=gdcm.ImageReader()
    reader.SetFileName(filename)
    reader.Read()
    gdcmimage=reader.GetImage()
    return ConvertNumpy.gdcm_to_numpy(gdcmimage)

image=loadDicomImage('mydicomfile.dcm')

plt.gray()
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

Note that If your DICOM data contains "padding" values significantly outside your image's air-bone range it might confuse imshow's auto-scaling; use vmax,vmin parameters to that call to specify the range you actually want to see, or implement your own window-levelling code (which is trivial in numpy).